# Google Bar Chart Unable Show Float Numbers

Tags: javascript, css, charts

I have some issue that my bar chart from google chart **not showing float numbers**, while im using others type of bar chart that google chart provide it works. But only this type of chart wont show the float numbers.

Here's the code I write : http://jsfiddle.net/2nf8x41g/1/

I hope that the solution is not change the type of declaration **var data** such as :

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn("Unit", "February", "Previous Month", "Previous 2 months");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: sir, hi, do you really need your table to be displayed vertically?

Comment: It's okay displayed horizontal  but it must a Material bar charts

Answer (score 0):

It could be this fix, but I didn't know if you will like it, replace

```
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('SLA_ONLINE'));
```

with

```
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('SLA_ONLINE'));
```

I have tried using vAxis.format (for vertical bar) however base on google docs 'This option is only supported for a continuous axis.'
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Data_Format

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, I was try that before but that's change the type of the bar chart